# How can I compare one level of a factor with all remaining levels in R

Tags: r, subset, levels

I have a dataframe similar to built-in InsectSprays (with factor and numeric data), but it contains 10+ numeric and 20+ factor vectors with few NAs. When I boxplot(numeric ~ factor), I notice that some levels stand out, and I want to be able to compare them with the rest.

As an example: InsectSprays contains a numeric vector called count (0:26), and a factor vector called sprays with levels: A, B, C, D, E and F. In InsectSprays, C is lowest, so I want to cbe able to compare C with all others.

I wrote a function for such numeric vectors:

```
num_interlevel <- function(df, variable, category){
  #find the levels of the categorizing parameter
  level.list <- levels(category)
  #build enough columns in the plot area
  par(mfrow=c(1,length(level.list)))
  for(i in 1:length(level.list)){
    #subset the df containing only the level in question
    variable.df <- na.omit(df[which(category == level.list[i]),])
    #subset the df containing all other levels
    category.df <- na.omit(df[which(category != level.list[i]),])
    boxplot(variable.df[, variable], category.df[, variable])
    p <- t.test(variable.df[, variable], category.df[, variable])$p.value
    title(paste(level.list[i], "=", p))
  }
}
```

and `num_interlevel(InsectSprays, "count", InsectSprays$spray)` gives me the result I want.

But when it comes to comparing factor vectors with each other (and I used tables for that), it doesn't work, simply because the dataframes are of different size, and more importantly, because this is a wrong way.

Then I thought that there may be an existing function for that, but couldn't find any.
Can anyone suggest a way/function to create one subset containing exactly one level and another subset containing all the other levels?

```
#dput:
structure(list(Yas = c(27, 18, 17, 18, 18), Cinsiyet = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Erkek", "Kadın"), class = "factor"), 
Ikamet = structure(c(5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Aileyle", 
"Akrabayla", "Arkadaşla", "Devlet yurdu", "Diğer", "Özel yurt", 
"Tek başına"), class = "factor"), Aile_birey = c(13, 9, 6, 
10, 6), Aile_gelir = c(700, 1000, 1500, 600, 800)), .Names = c("Yas", 
"Cinsiyet", "Ikamet", "Aile_birey", "Aile_gelir"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Edit

I reformed my functions **after James's answer**. This is certainly not an elegant solution, but I put it here for future reference:

```
n.compare <- function(df, variable, category){
  level.list <- levels(df[,category])
  par(mfrow=c(1,length(level.list)))
  for(i in 1:length(level.list)){
    boxplot(df[,variable] ~ (df[,category] == level.list[i]))
    p <- t.test(df[,variable] ~ (df[,category] == level.list[i]))$p.value
    title(paste(level.list[i], "=", p))
  }
}

f.compare <- function(df, variable, category){
  level.list <- levels(df[,category])
  par(mfrow=c(1,length(level.list)))
  for(i in 1:length(level.list)){
    print(paste(level.list[i]))
    print(table((df[,category] == level.list[i]), df[,variable]))
    writeLines("\n")
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use the `dput` function to include a small example of your data in the question.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by 'comparing factor vectors with each other'? E.g. given the data above, what would you like the result to be?

Comment: @Victor K. Sorry for the last comment below. I figured out that table function already provides everything I need in one place with the help of proportions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split up a data.frame, use `split`:

```
lapply(split(InsectSprays,InsectSprays$spray=="A"),summary)
$`FALSE`
     count       spray 
 Min.   : 0.00   A: 0  
 1st Qu.: 3.00   B:12  
 Median : 5.00   C:12  
 Mean   : 8.50   D:12  
 3rd Qu.:13.25   E:12  
 Max.   :26.00   F:12  

$`TRUE`
     count       spray 
 Min.   : 7.00   A:12  
 1st Qu.:11.50   B: 0  
 Median :14.00   C: 0  
 Mean   :14.50   D: 0  
 3rd Qu.:17.75   E: 0  
 Max.   :23.00   F: 0
```

Also consider the following:

```
boxplot(count~(spray=="A"),InsectSprays)
```

Comment: To be honest, your boxplot solution is at least super elegant compared with mine. However, despite this insight, I'm still struggling with comparing factor vectors with each other. The problem probably stems from that I'm not much acquainted with R yet (didn't even knew split). So is there any other hint for the table?

Comment: @barerd To compare means for example: `sapply(levels(InsectSprays$spray),function(x) lapply(split(InsectSprays,InsectSprays$spray==x),function(y) mean(y$count)))`